# Using innerhtml to write html with A LOT of quotes

Tags: php, javascript, quotes, innerhtml

I'm trying to call a function which writes a very long string of html to an element. The string will look similar to this;

```
   '<div id='gaugearray8'>
<p id='ANCPUB' class='plot' style='height:100px;width:175px;float:left;' title='0.0011217599587192' onClick=LowerLevelPrint([{"NumberSelected":1,"TargetPerc":[237.5],"KpiDescription":["Contribution&nbspof&nbspExternal&nbspRevenue"],"KpiName":["revcontrubionkpi"],"ValuetoPrint":[0.0011217599587192],"ValueNow":[19],"ValueCompare":[1693767],"Target":["8"],"KpiUnits":["Pounds"],"PercentCompare":[0.0011217599587192]}]) onmouseover=TopLevelLabel({"NumberSelected":1,"Description":["Contribution&nbspof&nbspExternal&nbspRevenue"],"GroupDescription":"Ancillary&nbspService&nbspPerformance"}) onmouseout=clearnew()></p>
<p id='CSPUB' class='plot' style='height:100px;width:175px;float:left;' title='21.855170547342' onClick=LowerLevelPrint([{"NumberSelected":7,"TargetPerc":[206.03360584712,8.8767313176762,10.356186537289,12.5,12.5,237.5,10.356186537289],"KpiDescription":["Operating&nbspCost&nbspper&nbspService&nbspKm","Revenue&nbspper&nbspService&nbspKm","Total&nbspCost&nbspper&nbspService&nbspKm","Claims&nbspCost&nbspper&nbspVehicle","Claims&nbspCost&nbspper&nbspDriver","Number&nbspof&nbspClaims&nbspLodged&nbspper&nbsp100,000km","Overheads&nbspCost&nbspper&nbspService&nbspKm"],"KpiName":["opcostperkmkpi","revenueperkmkpi","totalcostperkmkpi","claimspervehkpi","claimsperdriverkpi","claimslodgedkpi","overheadskpi"],"ValuetoPrint":[110.47252736225,5.6435200058102,5.434671444334,0.35610369406272,0.35829645079956,12.666666666667,18.054408207469],"ValueNow":[10.301680292356,0.62137119223733,0.62137119223733,1,1,19,0.62137119223733],"ValueCompare":[9.32510601353,11.010348002623,11.433463800009,280.81708128079,279.09849449204,150,3.4416591510336],"Target":["5","7","6","8","8","8","6"],"KpiUnits":["Pounds&nbspper&nbspKm","Pounds&nbspper&nbspKm","Pounds&nbspper&nbspKm","Pounds&nbspper&nbspVehicle","Pounds&nbspper&nbspDriver","Claims","Pounds&nbspa&nbspkm"],"PercentCompare":[110.47252736225,5.6435200058102,5.434671444334,0.35610369406272,0.35829645079956,12.666666666667,18.054408207469]}]) onmouseover=TopLevelLabel({"NumberSelected":7,"Description":["Operating&nbspCost&nbspper&nbspService&nbspKm","Revenue&nbspper&nbspService&nbspKm","Total&nbspCost&nbspper&nbspService&nbspKm","Claims&nbspCost&nbspper&nbspVehicle","Claims&nbspCost&nbspper&nbspDriver","Number&nbspof&nbspClaims&nbspLodged&nbspper&nbsp100,000km","Overheads&nbspCost&nbspper&nbspService&nbspKm"],"GroupDescription":"Core&nbspService&nbspPerformance"}) onmouseout=clearnew()></p>
<p id='ROPTUB' class='plot' style='height:100px;width:175px;float:left;' title='9.7292765723395' onClick=LowerLevelPrint([{"NumberSelected":2,"TargetPerc":[12.5,207.23684210526],"KpiDescription":["Revenue&nbspExpenditure&nbspper&nbspPassenger&nbspJourney","Cost&nbspPer&nbspHeadcount"],"KpiName":["revexperjourneykpi","coststaffkpi"],"ValuetoPrint":[19.044041148259,0.41451199641943],"ValueNow":[1,16.578947368421],"ValueCompare":[5.2509863437855,3999.6302909519],"Target":["8","8"],"KpiUnits":["Pounds&nbspper&nbspJourney","Pounds&nbspper&nbspStaff"],"PercentCompare":[19.044041148259,0.41451199641943]}]) onmouseover=TopLevelLabel({"NumberSelected":2,"Description":["Revenue&nbspExpenditure&nbspper&nbspPassenger&nbspJourney","Cost&nbspPer&nbspHeadcount"],"GroupDescription":"Resource&nbspOptimisation"}) onmouseout=clearnew()></p></div>';
```

Don't worry about disecting that as it's just an example of what can be sent. I'm assuming the problem is the multitude of quotes inside this string, as the javascript on the page entirely stops working when I include this function.

The above string is actually generated in a php loops, and the function I'm trying to use calls attempts

```
 document.getElementById('financearea').innerHTML = 
   '<?php $myview->PopulateContent($finance, 8, 'ub', 'UB', $a); ?>';
```

`
Which works correctly when its in the main page body, but won't run when using the innerHTML method.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how this could work?

This is the code on the php side - its created and echo'd in a loop

`$thisgoesinfile =
 "<p id='".$Group.$Depot."' class='plot' style='height:100px;width:175px;float:left;' title='".$TotalValuetoPrint."' onClick=LowerLevelPrint(".json_encode($result_set).") onmouseover=TopLevelLabel(".json_encode($Descriptions).") onmouseout=clearnew()></p>";`

Edit: I tried removing all the single quotes in the php string so now the string looks like

`document.getElementById('financearea').innerHTML = <div id=gaugearray8><p id=ANCPUB class=plot style=height:100px;width:175px;float:left; title=0.0011217599587192 onClick=LowerLevelPrint([{"NumberSelected":1,"TargetPerc":[237.5],"KpiDescription":["Contribution&nbspof&nbspExternal&nbspRevenue"],"KpiName":["revcontrubionkpi"],"ValuetoPrint":[0.0011217599587192],"ValueNow":[19],"ValueCompare":[1693767],"Target":["8"],"KpiUnits":["Pounds"],"PercentCompare":[0.0011217599587192]}]) onmouseover=TopLevelLabel({"NumberSelected":1,"Description":["Contribution&nbspof&nbspExternal&nbspRevenue"],"GroupDescription":"Ancillary&nbspService&nbspPerformance"}) onmouseout=clearnew()></p><p id=CSPUB class=plot style=height:100px;width:175px;float:left; title=21.855170547342 onClick=LowerLevelPrint([{"NumberSelected":7,"TargetPerc":[206.03360584712,8.8767313176762,10.356186537289,12.5,12.5,237.5,10.356186537289],"KpiDescription":["Operating&nbspCost&nbspper&nbspService&nbspKm","Revenue&nbspper&nbspService&nbspKm","Total&nbspCost&nbspper&nbspService&nbspKm","Claims&nbspCost&nbspper&nbspVehicle","Claims&nbspCost&nbspper&nbspDriver","Number&nbspof&nbspClaims&nbspLodged&nbspper&nbsp100,000km","Overheads&nbspCost&nbspper&nbspService&nbspKm"],"KpiName":["opcostperkmkpi","revenueperkmkpi","totalcostperkmkpi","claimspervehkpi","claimsperdriverkpi","claimslodgedkpi","overheadskpi"],"ValuetoPrint":[110.47252736225,5.6435200058102,5.434671444334,0.35610369406272,0.35829645079956,12.666666666667,18.054408207469],"ValueNow":[10.301680292356,0.62137119223733,0.62137119223733,1,1,19,0.62137119223733],"ValueCompare":[9.32510601353,11.010348002623,11.433463800009,280.81708128079,279.09849449204,150,3.4416591510336],"Target":["5","7","6","8","8","8","6"],"KpiUnits":["Pounds&nbspper&nbspKm","Pounds&nbspper&nbspKm","Pounds&nbspper&nbspKm","Pounds&nbspper&nbspVehicle","Pounds&nbspper&nbspDriver","Claims","Pounds&nbspa&nbspkm"],"PercentCompare":[110.47252736225,5.6435200058102,5.434671444334,0.35610369406272,0.35829645079956,12.666666666667,18.054408207469]}]) onmouseover=TopLevelLabel({"NumberSelected":7,"Description":["Operating&nbspCost&nbspper&nbspService&nbspKm","Revenue&nbspper&nbspService&nbspKm","Total&nbspCost&nbspper&nbspService&nbspKm","Claims&nbspCost&nbspper&nbspVehicle","Claims&nbspCost&nbspper&nbspDriver","Number&nbspof&nbspClaims&nbspLodged&nbspper&nbsp100,000km","Overheads&nbspCost&nbspper&nbspService&nbspKm"],"GroupDescription":"Core&nbspService&nbspPerformance"}) onmouseout=clearnew()></p><p id=ROPTUB class=plot style=height:100px;width:175px;float:left; title=9.7292765723395 onClick=LowerLevelPrint([{"NumberSelected":2,"TargetPerc":[12.5,207.23684210526],"KpiDescription":["Revenue&nbspExpenditure&nbspper&nbspPassenger&nbspJourney","Cost&nbspPer&nbspHeadcount"],"KpiName":["revexperjourneykpi","coststaffkpi"],"ValuetoPrint":[19.044041148259,0.41451199641943],"ValueNow":[1,16.578947368421],"ValueCompare":[5.2509863437855,3999.6302909519],"Target":["8","8"],"KpiUnits":["Pounds&nbspper&nbspJourney","Pounds&nbspper&nbspStaff"],"PercentCompare":[19.044041148259,0.41451199641943]}]) onmouseover=TopLevelLabel({"NumberSelected":2,"Description":["Revenue&nbspExpenditure&nbspper&nbspPassenger&nbspJourney","Cost&nbspPer&nbspHeadcount"],"GroupDescription":"Resource&nbspOptimisation"}) onmouseout=clearnew()></p></div>;`

But still not working.

Comment: Thanks @Pekka , was in the middle of doing that.

Comment: I believe you should be using single double quotes inside that string, also if i am not mistaken javascript will whine about line breaks like `unterminated string` or something. What JS error are you seeing?

Comment: No errors, it just doesn't run. The double quotes are automatically generated through a `json_encode` in the php function so not entirely sure how to replace them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the single quotes in the PHP output! :)

Replace the ' with \'

Comment: You've indirectly solved my problem. Escaping the quotes didn't work, so I tried deleting the single quotes entirely and removing the single quotes in the js side and it worked. Thanks for setting me on the right path indirectly

Comment: @steven that is a really kludgy workaround though, and will break if another level of quotes comes into play. I recommend you use the `json_encode()` approach

Answer (score 4):

Use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) rather than wrapping the text in single quotes yourself:

```
document.getElementById('financearea').innerHTML = <?php echo json_encode($myview->PopulateContent($finance, 8, 'ub', 'UB', $a)); ?>;
```

When you pass a string into `json_encode`, it will get wrapped in quotes and any quotes and other special characters within it will get correctly encoded for use as a JavaScript literal string. (This is a by-product of the fact that JSON is a subset of JavaScript's literal syntax.)

(I've also added an `echo` there; I'm not much of a PHP-head, so remove it if it's not needed, but you're not using short-tags, so...)

Comment: Nice idea. The resulting variable just needs slightly different addressing ( `variablename[0]`)

Comment: @Pekka: Thanks. Why? I've seen this used this way, again provided that the item passed in is a string and not an object...

Comment: yeah, true. Actually, this is better than my suggestion because I presume it will also take care of the line breaks. Removing mine

Comment: @Pekka: Line breaks, tabs, etc. :-)

Comment: Including this line makes the javascript on the page stop working. If I comment it out the js works again. I already use a `json_encode` inside the php to pass an array through an onclick (you can see the json encoded array in the top script) so not sure if this makes a difference?

Comment: @steven: I've probably messed up a minor aspect of the PHP part of the call. Fundamentally, `json_encode` should do exactly what you're looking for if you pass it in a string. dashing out the door, else I'd try it on a PHP box this end...

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you need to ensure you are escaping quotes within strings or the Javascript will break. A simple solution would be to use double-quotes **inside** the string, and use single-quotes to **delimit** the string.

`'<div id="gaugearray8">'`

Comment: Pekka's solution is much better though! :)

Comment: Added a line to the bottom showing the php side of the code. Php doesn't seem to like me attempting to delimit with single quotes though won't run.